# How can Excel dates default to short-date format when the year isn't typed?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, text-formatting

When typing dates into unformatted (General format) cells, Excel will change the format to a custom date format, but I'd rather it just stick to either the short or long format.

Examples:

```
11/28             : 28-Nov           (this isn't the common US format)
Nov 28            : 28-Nov           ("")
November 28, 2018 : 28-Nov-18        ("")
11/28/18          : 11/28/2018       (system Short Date)
11/28/2018        : 11/28/2018
11/28 4:00 pm     : 11/28/2018 16:00 (should be "4:00 pm")
```

The region format in the Region control panel is the standard short (M/d/yyyy) and long (dddd, MMMM d, yyyy) date and time (h:mm tt) formats for "English (United States)."

Is there a way to have Excel use the system/short format by default for dates or date-times when typed into a unformatted cell?

Thanks.

(There are several questions on changing the default format, but they are requesting displaying in something other than the system format, creating a custom format, or converting data to a new format.)

Answer (score -1):

**To get rid from the issue do the followings:**

- In `Control Panel` find & Click `Clock, Language and Region`.
- Check this Screen Shot & set parameters as show.
  [image]

  - Next, Click `Keyboard & Language` and find `Change Keyboard Button`.
  - From the `General Tab` ensure that `English (United State)-US` and Keyboard, `English (United State)` has been added.
  - Finish with `Ok`.

**Note:**

1. Then after, whenever you type date in `General Formatted Cell` will looks like, `11/29/2018`.
2. Function `=Now()` will return `11/29/2018 12:40`.
3. Function `=Today()` will show `11/29/18` and  `=TIME(12,40,0)` will return `12:40 PM`.

Comment: I think OP has already done this settings (The region format in the Region control panel is the standard short (M/d/yyyy) and long (dddd, MMMM d, yyyy) date and time (h:mm tt) formats for "English (United States).") also formatting works for some inputs, but not always. I don't see why keyboard layout would play any role here.

Comment: Yes, that's what I checked first. It's the standard formatting and all other date displays in the system look correct, just specific formats in Excel. Thank you though for your reply.